# How to create multiple sheets (tabs) in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a spreadsheet with 100+ sheets (tabs) with the specific name of each sheet.

I do not have any programming knowledge. Sorry for being ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

It will take some times ...

```
function createSheets() {
  for (var i=1;i<=100;i++){
    newSheetName = 'mySheet'+ ('00' + i).substring(1)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(newSheetName);
  }
}
```